# Using Laravel Image Intervention, how do I get image from URL and resize

Tags: laravel, intervention

I am trying to pull images from a url, resize them and store them in S3 buckets. The code works fine if I upload an image but pulling them from a url isn't working. This is where I am. If I replace the first line with the upload request it works.

```
$photo = file_get_contents('domain.com/img.jog');
$photo_link = time().'-'.$photo->getClientOriginalName();
$imageName = 'photos/'.$photo_link;

$extension = $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();

$image_resize = \Image::make($photo)->resize(2000, null, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
})->encode($extension);


$t = \Storage::disk('s3')->put($imageName, (string)$image_resize, 'public');
```

This gets me the error Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on string

How would I pull the image from a URL, resize it and store it in the Amazon bucket?

Comment: Did you try to append `https://` before domain name, it tries to get content of the local file I guess.

Comment: @CROSP just tried it, the site i'm pulling from isn't secure so it didn't work.

Comment: Hello @Scott, you have to pass full url of image with **http://** or **https://** in file_get_content() for make it work.

Comment: Hi @RaviGaudani I realize now that I didn't put that in my example, I have the http on it. I apologize for that. That being said I did figure this out after stepping away, to get the above to work, I just did an explode to the original file name, then got the last piece of the array ( the extension ) and once I had that it worked fine. I was not able to pull the extension the way I did originally using laravels baked in photo stuff. I will research more on file to gain a better understanding but for now that worked. Thanks for trying to help me though.